# Center camera on object in unity3d by programatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i wanted to center my camera on object once they are turn is active.. But, i am unable to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public GameObject UserPlayerPrefab;
public Vector3 v3;

void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(UserPlayerPrefab);
    }
```

i already tried that, but it gave me the error, said that i have to use Vector3. When i change the code to this one:

```
void Update()
        {
            transform.LookAt(v3);
        }
```

it works, but not the camera is not center on the object however it is center on the Tile (which is the Plane).

How do i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be trying to look at a prefab, but at an actual instance of the prefab. But, putting that aside, what you're looking for is this:

```
transform.LookAt(UserPlayerPrefab.transform.position);
```

Now, I would rather see something like this:

```
public GameObject UserPlayerPrefab;
private GameObject userPlayerInstance;


// Somewhere, not necessarily Start(), you instantiate the instance of the prefab
void Start()
{
    userPlayerInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(UserPlayerPrefab);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(userPlayerInstance.transform.position);
}
```